# C - Bus error (core dumped) - Matrix error

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {       
    int n, m, number, array[m][m];
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            scanf("%d ", &number);
            array[k][i] = number;
            printf("%d ", array[k][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("%d k=%di=%d\n", array[k][i], k, i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

We have an m*m matrix, in which we store values given on the users input. Afterwards we print the array to the users input. I am doing this in another program and this is were my program will crash, because of this code.

Does anyone know the bus error occurs?

Comment: `array[m][m]` with `m` being uninitialized?

Comment: what is the purpose of reading `n`?

Comment: This was copied from another code, this is the part where it crashes, in my orignnal code n is used.

Answer (score 4):

You declare a variable length array where the dimension is based on an uninitialized value. Postponing array declaration after having read in `m` should solve the problem:

```
int n,m, number;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
int array[m][m];
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, don't hesitate to accept the answer :-)